# may the queue leak data? or there is bug in my thread code?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have a data structure :

```
struct {
  mutex m;
  condition_variable cv_p2c;
  queue<int> qi;
  bool finished;
} sdf_inst;
```

and I have a producer that generate 100 integer and insert them into queue qi after getting lock.

```
void producer () { 
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) { 
    {
      unique_lock<mutex> ulck(sdf_inst.m);//LOCK
        sdf_inst.qi.push(i);
        cout<<"adding "<<i<<endl<<flush;
    } 
    sdf_inst.cv_p2c.notify_one();
  } 
  unique_lock<mutex> ulck(sdf_inst.m);//LOCK
  sdf_inst.finished=true;
  sdf_inst.cv_p2c.notify_one();
}
```

After all datas have been inserted, it will acquire the lock and set the finished flag, and exit.

And I have another consumer :

```
void consumer () { 
  while(true) { 
    unique_lock<mutex> ulck(sdf_inst.m);//LOCK
    sdf_inst.cv_p2c.wait(ulck,[]{return sdf_inst.qi.empty()==false || sdf_inst.finished==true ; });
    print_all();
    if(sdf_inst.finished=true) return;
  } 
}
```

It just acquire lock, and wait for notify from producer, and print all the data currently in the queue qi with the print_all function below:

```
void print_all () {
  while(sdf_inst.qi.empty()==false) {
    int i = sdf_inst.qi.front();
    sdf_inst.qi.pop();
    cout<<"shared_i "<< i <<endl<<flush;
  }
  return;
}
```

I think it should print all the 100 data, but sometimes it print only part of them.

I have studied the code carefully and find no error in synchronization, so may the lost data caused by the queue leakage?

Comment: Not a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and turned out to be a simple typographical error that basic compiler warnings should have caught. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of this problem, in `consumer()`:

```
if(sdf_inst.finished=true) return;
```

**should be**

```
if ( sdf_inst.finished )
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Didn't you get a warning about that?

Comment: I have just think about this, this is a common mistake. how should I turn on such a warning?

Comment: I have no idea, I would expect any decent modern C/C++ compiler to have all/most warnings on by default, I don't program in C/C++ so I unfortunately cannot tell you where to look, perhaps someone else can tell you this.

Comment: This particular problem, however, is the reason many C/C++ programmers end up switching their operands around, so that instead of `if (VARIABLE == VALUE)` they write `if (VALUE == VARIABLE)`, always. This way the compiler will refuse to compile the expression if the `VALUE` is a constant or a literal and you make that particular typo.

Comment: Haha, I used to program in C++ before 2007, and then turn to ocaml for its elegent support of polymorphism and side effect free semantics. I recently return to C++  and surprise by its significant improvement in the last 8 years, and also surprise to find how weak is my skill in C++ now.